# Packaging PHP or TAR into Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, cloud, tar, nas

1. Why I'm asking
2. Conditions
3. What I'm trying to do
4. What I've tried so far

**Why I'm asking**

The Seagate Personal Cloud (Network Attached Storage) I have can only install .rbw (Ruby on Windows) packages when installing 3rd party applications. Apparently, I can't access the cloud's root folder to just install a .tar from either Ubuntu or Windows (I can only access the drives that are shared), so I need to package into RBW.

**Conditions**

The Seagate Personal Cloud is hooked up to my router, and my computer accesses it over wi-fi. The NAS uses NAS OS. I have a Windows drive and an Ubuntu drive available to try whatever needs to be done. When I connect to it (over 192.168.2.x), I get a Web User Interface that logs in, and presents me with the NAS's applications/options/etc. There is no terminal available from the WebUI.

**What I'm trying to do**

ownCloud is available for download as a 3rd party application, from the WebUI's App Manager, or for download from Seagate's website as a .rbw file. However, the packaged .rbw file is v6, but ownCloud is up to v8 now, and ownCloud can't update from my NAS, because it can't get the permissions (and since I can't access the NAS root folders, I can't seem to chmod it's folders to allow anything to write to it).

**What I've tried so far**

I've tried accessing it from both Win/Ubu drives over the network - only accesses the shared folders.
And with WebDAV - only accesses the shared folders.
And S/FTP both - only shared folders.
And "SDrive" (a Windows program that comes with it) - only shared folders.
And I've tried "Take Ownership" with Windows, but doesn't do anything.
And just clicking the "Update" button from ownCloud - says it doesn't have write access.

---

So finally, I'm trying to find out how to package a .tar (<--mainly) or .php into Ruby (ownCloud can install with a PHP file). Plus, it would be nice to learn how to package .tar's into Ruby, so that I can just do the same thing with multiple other programs, and submit those .rbw's to each program's maintainers, so that they can provide it to others who need that extension for their NAS.

I'm a basic user, so I'm sorry and will clarify if something here didn't make much sense.

Comment: @jrochkind - What's unlikely? It's definitely possible, since the Seagate 3rd party app already provides ownCloud as a .rbw file, which you can import into your NAS. If it's been done, then I need to find the people who can do it. Or are you saying something else is unlikely?

Comment: Well, so far I've figured out that .rbw opens up as an archive. I'm attempting to go through and replace all of the relevant codes and files with the updated v8. If it works, I'll leave a link to the finished product here - unless someone else comes up with a better answer before that time.

Answer (score 2):

For the Seagate Personal Cloud the RBW files are created within Seagate's Virtual machine.  See https://www.seagate.com/nasos/SDK/0.7/  for all kinds of information.  Taking an old rbw file and changing a few files,  will not work easily.

If your Seagate device is like mine where by default the ssh server is turned off and not listed as a service in the the Web menus, you can actually turn it on.  Access your device as http://my.device.com/?appdev=1 where the ( my.device.com your device.  It might be 192.168.1.??? if you just have an ip number )  Go to the services menu and disable sftp and then enable ssh.  The root password is what you used for your admin account when you first set-up the device.

P.S.  There is now a rbw file for Owncloud 9.0.2 in the Owncloud forums.